# Flash ActionScript 2 JSON returning [object Object]

Tags: json, actionscript

I'm trying to get the value of a JSON object in ActionScript 2 but it keeps returning undefined or [object Object].

Here is my code:

```
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < oProduct.prosAndCons.pros.length; i++) {
        if (i == oProduct.prosAndCons.pros.length) {
            break;
        };
        //
        mcProsCons.txtPros.htmlText += oProduct.prosAndCons.pros[i]+ "<br /><br />";
    };
```

And here is the returned JSON:

```
{
    "prosAndCons": {
        "pros": [
            {
                "cute animals": {
                    "link": "http://searchreviews.com/best/q-1661072-cute-animals",
                    "excerptCount": 1,
                    "excerpt": "Cute songs and cute animals."
                }
            },
            {
                "cute toy": {
                    "link": "http://searchreviews.com/best/q-3584162-cute-toy",
                    "excerptCount": 6,
                    "excerpt": "All in all it's a very cute toy that holds up to a lot of use."
                }
            },
            {
                "cute songs": {
                    "link": "http://searchreviews.com/best/q-1769522-cute-songs",
                    "excerptCount" :2,
                    "excerpt": "Cute songs and cute animals."
                }
            },
            {
                "chunky magnetic letters": {
                    "link": "http://searchreviews.com/best/q-662-chunky-magnetic-letters",
                    "excerptCount": 1,
                    "excerpt": "The chunky magnetic letters are perfect for little hands and the magnets that hold them to the fridge are enclosed so there is no worry of a swallow hazard."
                }
            },
            {
                "catchy song": {
                    "link": "http://searchreviews.com/best/q-672-catchy-song",
                    "excerptCount": 4,
                    "excerpt": "\" You made a match, look what you have done ,\" It's a very catchy song!"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? It's been awhile since I coded in AS2 w/ JSON.

Comment: Hint: `prosAndCons.pros[0]` is an object.

Comment: Take a look at the edit I made to your JSON and see if you can spot anything.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- `prosAndCons.pros[0]` is an Object.
- There are a total of 5 objects in the array `prosAndCons.pros`, each containing an inner object represented by the following:

  1. "cute animals"
  2. "cute toy"
  3. "cute songs"
  4. "chunky magnetic letters"
  5. "catchy song"
- Each of those has three properties:

  1. "link"
  2. "excerptCount"
  3. "excerpt"

---

Try using this as your JSON (if you're able to edit it):

```
{"prosAndCons":{"pros":[{"name":"cute animals","link":"http://searchreviews.com/best/q-1661072-cute-animals","excerptCount":1,"excerpt":"Cute songs and cute animals."},{"name":"cute toy","link":"http://searchreviews.com/best/q-3584162-cute-toy","excerptCount":6,"excerpt":"All in all it's a very cute toy that holds up to a lot of use."},{"name":"cute songs","link":"http://searchreviews.com/best/q-1769522-cute-songs","excerptCount":2,"excerpt":"Cute songs and cute animals."},{"name":"cute magnetic letters","link":"http://searchreviews.com/best/q-662-chunky-magnetic-letters","excerptCount":1,"excerpt":"The chunky magnetic letters are perfect for little hands and the magnets that hold them to the fridge are enclosed so there is no worry of a swallow hazard."},{"name":"cute song","link":"http://searchreviews.com/best/q-672-catchy-song","excerptCount":4,"excerpt":"\" You made a match, look what you have done ,\" It's a very catchy song!"}]}}
```

With this you'll be able to do something like this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < oProduct.prosAndCons.pros.length; i++)
{
    var pro:Object = oProduct.prosAndCons.pros[i];

    trace(pro.name);
    trace(pro.link);
}
```

Comment: It's in a strange format that will make it pretty much impossible to work with the information in each object, because each is assigned to a random property name like "cute animals".

Comment: I have sent a request to see it they will update their api. I was hoping to get this completed tonight but it looks like I will have to wait another day.

Comment: Shouldn't this work? (was trying for testing):
var sTestStr = oProduct.prosAndCons.pros["cute animals"].link;
Still returns undefined.

Comment: Yeah that should work, assuming you've de-serialized your JSON data with a JSON library and assigned the result to `oProduct`.